# multiple queries on 1 button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to perform 2 queries in one button click. I tried the 
string query = "first query";
query+="second query";
But this didn't work it shows error.

I have now created 2 separate connections like below:

```
 try
        {
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringDatabase"].ConnectionString);
            //open connection with database
            conn1.Open();

            //query to select all users with teh given username
            SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("insert into artikulli (tema,abstrakti, kategoria_id, keywords ) values (@tema, @abstrakti, @kategoria, @keywords)", conn1);

            // comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", iD);
            com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tema", InputTitle.Value);
            com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abstrakti", TextareaAbstract.Value);
            com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kategoria", DropdownCategory.Value);
            com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keywords", InputTags.Value);
            //execute queries
            com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn1.Close();

            if (FileUploadArtikull.HasFile)
            {
                int filesize = FileUploadArtikull.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                if (filesize > 4194304)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Maximumi i madhesise eshte 4MB');", true);
                }
                else
                {

                    string filename = "artikuj/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadArtikull.PostedFile.FileName);
                    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringDatabase"].ConnectionString);
                    SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("insert into artikulli(path) values ('" + filename + "')", conn2);
                    //open connection with database
                    conn2.Open();
                    com2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    FileUploadArtikull.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/artikuj\\" + FileUploadArtikull.FileName));
                    Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Ju nuk keni perzgjedhur asnje file');", true);  
            }
        }
```

But the problem is that only the second query is performed and the firs is saved as null in database

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the problem is that only the second query is performed and the first is saved as null in database

Comment: why not just use stored proc for this?

Comment: how to do this? sorry but I am new at asp.net

Comment: Why do you need two connections?

Comment: because with one it didn't work

Comment: @Arual: What did not work?

Comment: didn't saved any thing in db

Comment: you should use transactions for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, there is no reason to open two connections. In addition, the C# language has evolved, so I recommend using the power given by the new language constructs (`using`, `var`).

Here is an improved version that should work assuming that the values you bind to your parameters are valid:

```
try
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringDatabase"].ConnectionString))
    {
        //open connection with database
        connection.Open();

        //query to select all users with teh given username
        using(var command1 = new SqlCommand("insert into artikulli (tema,abstrakti, kategoria_id, keywords ) values (@tema, @abstrakti, @kategoria, @keywords)", connection))
        {
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tema", InputTitle.Value);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abstrakti", TextareaAbstract.Value);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kategoria", DropdownCategory.Value);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keywords", InputTags.Value);

            //execute first query
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        //build second query
        string filename = "artikuj/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadArtikull.PostedFile.FileName);
        using(SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("insert into artikulli(path) values (@filename)", connection))
        {
            //add parameters
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", filename);

            //execute second query
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
//TODO: add some exception handling
//simply wrapping code in a try block has no effect without a catch/finally
```

Comment: now it is not saving the path of file, is not performing the second query

Comment: @Aural: There was an error in the second statement, should work now.

Comment: it is sth wrong because it saves 2 rows in db, one with the first query saving and path is null and the second saves only path and other data null. the point is that i have path and other data at the same table and I want to save both queries in the same table row

Comment: @Arual: That information was completely missing. But that leads to another question: do you know how a SQL INSERT statement works?

Comment: sorry it is my fault, i didn't explained my problem well. I know how insert works and I realy feel so stupid right now

Comment: @Arual: Haha, sorry, thought you have no clue about SQL. Sometimes it is just necessary that someone else takes a look :)

Answer (score -1):

Try below code, No need to open the connection twice

```
string query1 = "insert into artikulli (tema,abstrakti, kategoria_id, keywords ) values (@tema, @abstrakti, @kategoria, @keywords)";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringDatabase"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand com1= new SqlCommand(query1, conn);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tema", InputTitle.Value);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abstrakti", TextareaAbstract.Value);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kategoria", DropdownCategory.Value);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keywords", InputTags.Value);

string query2 = "insert into artikulli(path) values ('" + filename + "')", conn);

comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

comm.CommandText = query2;
comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: CS0103: The name 'connManag' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry use this one SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringDatabase"].ConnectionString);

Comment: it is saving nothing now. No conn.openand close? what about com1 where is executed? please edit my question because I messed up the code :(

Comment: This code does not work, `comm` is never declared nor assigned